# Basic Java Inheritance

Tags: java, inheritance

I have a quick question about inheritance. Currently, I am making a simple program that reenacts the process you would do to make a custom block while modding Minecraft with forge.

I have the super class `Block`:

```
public class Block {
    public String name;
    public int id;
    public int height = 16;

    public Block(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void onRightClick() {
        System.out.println("You Right Clicked!");
    }

    public void setUnlocalizedName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Then I have made two child classes. They are identical, but here is one just as a reference.

```
package com.andrewfurniss;

public class GrassBlock extends Block {
    public GrassBlock(int id) {
        super(id);
        this.setUnlocalizedName("DirtBlock");
    }
}
```

The other class is called `DirtBlock`. When I print out the names it only prints out whatever name I declared second. Why is that?

Comment: Could you post the code for "When I print out the names"?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm not clear on what you're asking. What do you mean by `"it only prints out whatever name I declared second..."`? I see that you've declared a name field only once. As a side note, I'd make all the fields private, not public and would consider creating constructors that can take id and name, and then set the name via a super constructor call.

Comment: what's the output? why it's not unexpected?

Comment: You have a getter for name in super class but name is public. Making all of your fields public could be bad practice. In super class it is common to make them private or protected (private for the inheritance line).

Answer (score 1):

It is because you set a wrong name in the `GrassBlock`:

```
this.setUnlocalizedName("DirtBlock");
```

Probably a copy-paste mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you're doing:

```
public void ToDo(){
    Block b = new GrassBlock(0);
    b = new DirtBlock(1);

   System.out.println(b.getName());
}
```

??
We need the code you're using to print then name...

I edit, why are you writing "dirtblock" on grassblock ctor?? Maybe it can be that.